# Read 2x chars from array as a short?

Tags: c++, arrays, byte, bit

Why does the following not interpret the two chars as a group of 16 bits?

```
char c[2];
c[0] = 2;
c[1]= 2;
short a = short(c[0]);
```

I'd like two read the array as all 16 bits together? What is the fastest (latency) way to do this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit changed it to C++ only.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write into the actual short. You can do it like this:

```
short a;
unsigned char * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&a);

p[0] = 2;
p[1] = 2;
```

Comment: Why do we not have "short" inside the reinterpret_cast brackets? unsigned char * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short *>(&a);?

Comment: @user3811839: Why? `&a` is already a `short *`. What we wanted was to get access at the individual bytes making up the short.

Comment: I understand that :) I thought the type inside the angled brackets was supposed to be your "destination type" (ie short in this case)?

Answer (score 2):

The most portable way to get whatever the native byte ordering of the machine is:

```
char c[] = { whatever, from whatever source };
short s;
memcpy(&s, c + offset, sizeof (short));
```

Most optimizing compilers will turn this into the equivalent of

```
short s = *(short*)(c + offset); // C-style cast, equivalent to C++ reinterpret_cast
```

(which is just a single typically 16-bit memory access, extremely fast)

with the important distinction that the compiler is aware of the aliasing, no language rules are violated.  The compiler also will do whatever is needful to handle alignment on architectures where that is important.

---

Portable code for specific byte ordering is even simpler:

```
short s = (c[offset + 1] << 8) | (uint8_t)c[offset]; // little-endian
short s = (c[offset] << 8) | (uint8_t)c[offset + 1]; // big-endian
```

and when the specified byte order matches the machine, the optimizer will again (with very high likelihood) generate the single 16-bit access instruction.

Comment: Recommend `char c[]` --> `char c[sizeof (short)]`.

Comment: @chux: I'm assuming the two elements grabbed could be a subset of the total data.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "|" bitwise OR, rather than addition?

Comment: @user3811839: This is fundamentally a bitwise operation.  Place this byte in that set of bits, place the other byte in this set of bits, and use all the set bits from both.  It's not a mathematical operation.  You don't want carry, overflow, sign extension, or any of the other features of arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1):

You're taking the first `char`, which is `2`, and then you're transforming *that* single value into a `short`. It's too late: by the time the cast occurs your code has totally forgotten about that other `char`. You only fed one of them into the cast.

You have to play with pointers to pretend to the compiler that you have a *single* object that's 16 bits wide, and you can do that with `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a union! That way after you read the data into your chars, you can immediately treat that data as if it were already a short.

Depending on what you need, you may not even need to copy the short after, and just use the "short s" as is :)

```
union
{
    char c[2];
    short s;
}
c[0] = 2;
c[1] = 2;

short a = s;
```

In your other question, you asked why this was a problem in the first place.

When you access c[0], you're accessing a char. You'd hoped that the computer would "know" you wanted the surrounding data as well. The access of c[0] is explicitly saying that you only want to access the data in that single char.

Comment: In C++, reading from an inactive union member is undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ty, that was interesting to read up on. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only assigning the value of c[0] to a. Your last line is identical to:

```
short a = c[0];
```

One way to do what you want is to copy c[0] and c[1] using bitwise operations:

```
short a = (short)(c[0] + (c[1] << 8));
```

Note that I cast the result to (short) since gcc converts bitwise results to int.

Comment: You also need to mask or otherwise convert `c[0]` in case it is negative.

Comment: Matt's right, the "usual integral promotions" will cause sign extension.